Sudden dropdown from downloads of Apple App Store
Does someone has an app in Apple App Store and downloads are dropped to 0 without an specific reason?
I changed my metadata to keywords that are currently ranking high withon my app and downloads still dropping.
App Store doesn't aloe me to change primary language to English US. I have my primary language on English CAN and all my localization metadata drives my to English US on Apple searches.
